# HTTPSConnectionPool error

Tags: python, web-scraping, httpconnection

I am trying to scrape data with Python 3.x from particular websites, and for some sites it won't let me scrape and it shows the error like this:

> raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='....', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]

This is happening often with e-mail verification as well. I would like to know how to handle these kind of errors and what is the solution?

Thank you for your time.

P.S. Code below:

```
enrich_url = "..."

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent':ua.chrome}
website = requests.get(enrich_url, headers=header) <--- (error is showing here)

soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Post the code that is throwing this error. and the website for which it is not working

Comment: Updated the question with the part that is showing the error! :-)